# How to add element to array with Drools (mvel)

Tags: drools, mvel

I need insert a new value in a exist array with Drools. My example:

```
rule "insert new address"
dialect "java"
when
     $data : Data( source.address != null)
then
     Address address = (Address) $data.source.address
     System.out.println("Element: "+address );
     $data.target.addressList.add(address);
end
```

The error that happend is this:
Exception executing consequence for rule "insert new address" in rules: [Error: $data.target.addressList.add(address): null]

**EDIT**: Added the model

```
public class Data {
  private Source source;
  private Client target;
}

public class Source {
  ...
  private Address address;
}

public class Client {
  ...
  private List<Address> addressList;
}
```

Comment: What array? There's no array in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the question in your title, which is how to add an element to array -- the answer is basically "the same way you would in Java."

To answer the question you actually asked, which has no arrays, your error is effectively a NullPointerException, or another indicator that the field cannot be modified (eg an immutable list.)

This:

```
Error: $data.target.addressList.add(address): null]
```

Means that either `$data.target` or `$data.target.addressList` is null, or possibly `$data.target.addressList` is an immutable list.

Make sure that whatever "target" is has been initialized, and that its "addressList" is also initialized as a mutable list type.

Comment: If y put this: 
System.out.println("Size"+$data.target.addressList.size()); the app write "3" (that is correct because exist 3 elements)

Comment: I've addded the model in post to see it

Comment: You've not indicated how or when any of these models are initialized, nor what their getters are.

Comment: The models is a DTO, come from a client like a JSON. I've found the problem. The problem is this: 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException for inmmutability.
I've created a method with this 
this.addressList = new ArrayList<>(this.addressList); and then .add works.